# TCP/IP Connects and Sends But Doesn't Work After Initial Sends

Tags: java, android, tcpclient, tcp

HELP! I'm Going Crazy! I'm using a Visual Basic 6.0 Winsock for the server. I'm able to keep an active connection and I even receive from my Android App to the VB App "VER:Android,LAT:28.111921,LNG:-81.950433,ID:1038263,SND:0,VDO:0"> Which I parse and put the data in their fields.

After my initial connection I try to send a simple message from VB to the Server and I never receive it. What I do notice whenever I close my VB.NET app I recieve this in my LogCat:

11-26 15:38:16.567: I/TcpClient(986): received: null

I'm new to Android any help would be highly appreciated. I need help trying to recieve and send messages back and forth through my Client(Android) and Server(VB)

```
 package com.WheresMySon;


 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.TextView;



 public class TcpClient extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new TcpClientTask().execute();

}


class TcpClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 1234;
    private boolean error = false;
    Boolean SocketStarted = false;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", TCP_SERVER_PORT);


                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

            //send output msg
            String outMsg = "VER:Android,LAT:28.111921,LNG:-81.950433,ID:1038263,SND:0,VDO:0";
            out.write(outMsg);
            out.flush();

            Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);

            //accept server response

            String inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");

            Log.i("TcpClient", "received: " + inMsg);



            //close connection
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        if(error) {
            // Something bad happened

        }
        else {
            // Success


        }

    }
}

//replace runTcpClient() at onCreate with this method if you want to run tcp client as a service
private void runTcpClientAsService() {
    Intent lIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), TcpClientService.class);
    this.startService(lIntent);
}

 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how winsocks work, but are you flushing from VB? `readLine` also reads until the next line separator, so does your method from sending from VB include a line separator?

Comment: line seperator, for example vbcrlf?

Comment: I think your right Austin. For whatever reason it doesn't matter how many times I send the data using VB (Winsock1.Senddata ("test")) it will not post to the iLog until the connection is closed.

Comment: I put \n in the end of all my data that sent. I sent a couple messages and never recieved them from the server. But once I closed the connection BOOM all the times I sent the data it sent at once. 11-26 17:15:46.948: I/TcpClient(694): received: Connection Accepted\nHEY!\nHEY!\nTXT:Test\nTXT:Test\nTXT:Test\n

Comment: I think the most likely explanation is as Austin suggests, you're not flushing your NetworkStream by calling Flush() after you've called your Write() in your VB server.

Comment: The question is how do you "Flush()" in Visual Basic Server?